# Inconsistent Date.now() values

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, multiplayer

I built an HTML5 multiplayer game that depends on having a reasonably accurate time sync between server and client. For the most part, the algorithm I use is very accurate -- all it does is estimate what the client-server time delta is, i.e. the difference between the current time on the server and the current time on client. For example, if the server time is exactly 5 seconds ahead of the client time, the time delta is 5000 ms.

The client and server (node.js) are both written in Javascript. The algorithm works as follows:

1. Record time on the client:
   `var clientTime = Date.now();`
2. Ping the server. When the server receives the message, it *immediately* sends a response containing just one thing: the time on the server when the message was received.

   ```
   var serverTime = Date.now();
   // Send serverTime to the client
   ```
3. When the client receives the server response, *immediately* record the time:
   `var clientTime2 = Date.now();`

Now, we know that when the server received the message, the client time *must* have been somewhere between `clientTime` and `clientTime2`.

If the server received the message when client time was `clientTime` (i.e. client->server request took 0ms somehow), then the time delta is
`var delta1 = (serverTime - clientTime);`

If the server received the message when client time was `clientTime` (i.e. server->client response took 0ms somehow), then the time delta is
`var delta2 = (serverTime - clientTime2)`.

Thus we can safely say that the time delta is somewhere between `delta1` and `delta2`. Now, repeat this process a bunch of times, each time narrowing the range based on whatever results you got, and you can get a pretty good estimate of the time delta.

I've tested this hundreds of times on 7 different browsers and multiple machines and have *never* had any issue with it. It's never been inconsistent.

---

The issue, though, is that my server logs show that, every now and then, a few people will get **wildly** inconsistent time sync results. Here is an **actual** example of one player's time sync:

The client went through **74** cycles of the above algorithm and successfully narrow the range of possible time deltas to: [-186460, -186431] without a single inconsistency. **29ms accuracy**.

On the 75th cycle, possibly a few seconds after the 74th cycle, the client calculated the range of possible time deltas to be: [-601, -596]. **5ms accuracy**, except for it's extremely inconsistent with the past 74 cycles: it's **3 minutes off!**

I would blame this on crazy edge cases, except it happens almost 100 times a day... how could this happen? Is there any possible error when using `Date.now()`?

Comment: You'll almost certainly need to post the actual code you're using for this whole process in order to get a definitive answer. Any answers without seeing the code will merely be speculation.

Comment: That's not accurate; `Date.now()` is based on UTC. Of course, it's based on what time the client thinks it is.

Comment: How about, An internet time sync happened setting the clock back to the correct time since apparently it was 3 min slow.

Comment: Is there any other data associated with these random inconsistencies? Perhaps a general time of day (in your server or in the client's timezone)? Could one or the other (or both?!) be performing an internet time sync and mostly fixing the drift?

Comment: the client and server are assumed to have different times as it is, as long as Date.now() never "freezes" or anything this algorithm is theoretically perfect.

Comment: @JonSG The client had to have had a decent internet connection to even start the game in the first place though... I don't know much about how computers do internet time syncs but is it reasonable to think that a 3 minute jump could happen for so many people?

Comment: I tried basic googling but didn't find anything great, can anyone explain to me more about internet time sync? I thought it was safe to assume a computer with a decent internet connection would never randomly jump in time 3 minutes... also my servers are Ubuntu from DigitalOcean hosted in their NYC center if that's relevant.

Comment: @Victor Zhou it is *totally* reasonable to expect a 3 minute drift for a lot of people. A time sync will typically only happen once every [period of time] (let's say a week, for the argument but it could be much longer or a bit shorter. Almost never as often as once a day). In the in between time, the clock is only kept in sync by the processor ticking every 1000ms, but that's a finicky thing, and countless variables could mess with it. Under or over powered processors could count time improperly, dying processors could miss ticks, etc.

Comment: @rockerest wow, I had no idea. I remember one time seeing a log where a client had 20 or so inconsistencies in a row, each one off by about 1 second. Could that have been because his clock was gradually correcting itself over some span of time so the time delta kept growing?

Comment: I think the default sync period in windows is like a week so if you had 1000 clients that would be about on average one every 10 mins.  It might be more frequent on mobile devices as they can sync based off of several sources.  This of course might not be the problem at all.  I'm just giving my best guess.  Perhaps rather than log just the deltas you log the timestamps as well.  that would give you a better indication of what is happening

Comment: `performance.now()` is both more precise and doesn't drift if OS updates the time

Comment: @dandavis how do you know it doesn't drift, do you have a source? That would be an excellent solution if that was the case.

Comment: @Victor Zhou, `performance.now()` doesn't drift because it's not technically the exact time. The implementation is guaranteed to increment at a constant rate instead of representing the time exactly (which can drift, be adjusted manually, be smeared, etc.). But it sounds like you don't need the time, per se, you just need an incrementing number, which `performance.now()` would provide.

Comment: wow, performance.now() is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()`, because `performance.now()` is monotonically increasing and not subject to clock drift. See the comments, thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

Your difficulty is that you depend on estimating round-trip times to the server, over an Internet that has variance in round-trip times. Sometimes that variance will be unexpectedly substantial, as in cases where temporary congestion and large router buffers delay a single message far longer than normal. (Cf "bufferbloat".)

Your second difficulty is that you are using self-reported client times, and that means that if a client has a clock that's weird it will look to you like a round-trip estimation gone wrong. As another poster noted, internet time protocols will sometimes slew a clock rapidly to correct from local timekeeping anomalies.

What it sounds like is that you need some filtering in your code that takes into account previous results so that when you get an anomalous result you don't immediately accept it as true.

Comment: There is filtering, I don't automatically accept it as true. The algorithm doesn't care at all about any kind of congestion or delays, though. Even if client -> server took 50ms and server -> client took 6000 ms, there would still be no inconsistencies (I've tested this to double check). The only way I can think of an inconsistency occurring is if either client or server time were to instantly jump back / forward in time for whatever reason...

Comment: This is an intro to how the Network Time Protocol handles changes in time, e.g. when a local clock drifts away from the real time.  http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm

Comment: thanks, do you have a recommendation for a specific section to read? That's a pretty long article haha

Comment: Yes! Network Time Protocol is pretty ancient, and the documentation matches. Look at the bit about "6. Operating System Clock Interface".

Comment: Time synchronization is ***really hard***. Don't assume your homegrown implementation is anywhere close to correct. Study NTP and its successors carefully.